# I/flutter ( 9637): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I trying to solved it. But I am getting this problem particular user specific. Some user's data display correctly but Some data giving this error. I could not understand where is the problem.

This is the Screen Code

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: user.fetchData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return quickInfo(snapshot.data);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                print(snapshot.error);
                return Text("Something Error. Try again later");
              }

              return Container(
                height: 50,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text("Loading..."),
              );
            },
          ),
```

quickInfo Methods Code

```
Widget quickInfo(User user) {
    var todayVisits = visitByDay(user);
    var monthlyVisits = visitByMonth(user);

    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    todayVisits.toString() ?? '0',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text("Today Visits"),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    monthlyVisits.toString() ?? '0',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text("Monthly Visits"),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    user.clients.length.toString() ?? '0',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text("Total Clients"),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 30,
            thickness: 2.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Rest API Data Sample

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Shibaji Debnath",
  "mobile": "8981009499",
  "sms_token": null,
  "mobile_verified_at": null,
  "email": "shibaji@gmail.com",
  "email_token": null,
  "email_verified_at": null,
  "password": "$2y$10$HVZGCGnmLdluKx.nBBUKseP.3SYwb/t8.9C4aoH9ckibJRSjWr23W",
  "remember_token": null,
  "avatar": null,
  "address": "Dum Dum",
  "city": "Kolkata",
  "state": "West Bengal",
  "country": "India",
  "pincode": 700074,
  "location_id": 1,
  "travelled": "Dum Dum",
  "adharcard": "345678",
  "pancard": "345678",
  "specialisation": "0",
  "services": null,
  "min_charge": "500",
  "max_charge": "1000",
  "online_charge": null,
  "qualification": "MCOM",
  "experience": "All",
  "language": null,
  "active": "0",
  "varify": "1",
  "payment_mode": null,
  "created_at": "2020-08-11T08:21:31.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2020-08-27T16:13:58.000000Z",
  "rating": "2.7",
  "clients": [
    {
      "id": 40,
      "client_id": 1,
      "perpose": "Astrology",
      "details": "Know my Future",
      "when": "2020-08-22 16:00",
      "accepted_by": 1,
      "name": "Shibaji Debnath",
      "mobile": "8981009499",
      "email": "imshibaji@gmail.com",
      "org_name": "Personal",
      "address": "12/2 Kobi Madam Mitra Lane",
      "city": "Kolkata",
      "state": "West Bengal",
      "pincode": "700087",
      "country": "India",
      "latitude": null,
      "longitude": null,
      "client_ip": null,
      "device": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-19T08:30:05.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-09-01T19:13:36.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 47,
      "client_id": 30,
      "perpose": "Pooja",
      "details": "Laxmi Narayana Puja",
      "when": "2020-08-29 14:00",
      "accepted_by": 1,
      "name": "Bimal Roy",
      "mobile": "6458998590",
      "email": "bimal@abc.com",
      "org_name": "My House",
      "address": "Kumarpara, Dum Dum Cant. Gorabazar.",
      "city": "Kolkata",
      "state": "West Bengal",
      "pincode": "700028",
      "country": "India",
      "latitude": null,
      "longitude": null,
      "client_ip": null,
      "device": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T08:17:47.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-09-01T19:13:25.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 48,
      "client_id": 31,
      "perpose": "Nadi",
      "details": "Nahhii hhj",
      "when": "2020-09-02 20:01",
      "accepted_by": 1,
      "name": "Shyam Ghose",
      "mobile": "6787998780",
      "email": "shyam@abc.com",
      "org_name": "House Party",
      "address": "Desmukh Part",
      "city": "Kolkata",
      "state": "West Bengal",
      "pincode": "700089",
      "country": "India",
      "latitude": null,
      "longitude": null,
      "client_ip": null,
      "device": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T15:06:43.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-09-01T19:13:22.000000Z"
    }
  ],
  "visits": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "pandit_activity_id": 7,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-24 02:10:18",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-23T20:40:18.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-23T20:40:18.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "pandit_activity_id": 7,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-24 02:12:40",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-23T20:42:40.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-23T20:42:40.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "pandit_activity_id": 7,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-24 02:12:58",
      "created_at": "2020-08-23T20:42:58.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-23T20:42:58.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "pandit_activity_id": 2,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-24 02:21:56",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-23T20:51:56.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-23T20:51:56.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "pandit_activity_id": 2,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-24 02:22:00",
      "created_at": "2020-08-23T20:52:00.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-23T20:52:00.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "pandit_activity_id": 5,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-24 02:22:27",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-23T20:52:27.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-23T20:52:27.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "pandit_activity_id": 5,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-24 02:22:30",
      "created_at": "2020-08-23T20:52:30.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-23T20:52:30.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "pandit_activity_id": 3,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-24 02:23:19",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-23T20:53:19.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-23T20:53:19.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "pandit_activity_id": 3,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-24 02:23:27",
      "created_at": "2020-08-23T20:53:27.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-23T20:53:27.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "pandit_activity_id": 5,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-24 15:08:02",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-24T09:38:02.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-24T09:38:02.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "pandit_activity_id": 5,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-24 15:08:06",
      "created_at": "2020-08-24T09:38:06.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-24T09:38:06.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "pandit_activity_id": 8,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-24 22:27:05",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-24T16:57:05.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-24T16:57:05.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "pandit_activity_id": 8,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-24 22:27:09",
      "created_at": "2020-08-24T16:57:09.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-24T16:57:09.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "pandit_activity_id": 8,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-24 22:27:37",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-24T16:57:37.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-24T16:57:37.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 15,
      "pandit_activity_id": 8,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-24 22:27:43",
      "created_at": "2020-08-24T16:57:43.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-24T16:57:43.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "pandit_activity_id": 8,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-24 22:36:47",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-24T17:06:47.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-24T17:06:47.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "pandit_activity_id": 8,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-24 22:36:51",
      "created_at": "2020-08-24T17:06:51.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-24T17:06:51.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "pandit_activity_id": 4,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-26 14:31:12",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T09:01:12.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T09:01:12.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 19,
      "pandit_activity_id": 4,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-26 14:32:04",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T09:02:04.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T09:02:04.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 20,
      "pandit_activity_id": 6,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-26 14:32:21",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T09:02:21.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T09:02:21.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 21,
      "pandit_activity_id": 6,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-26 15:14:01",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T09:44:01.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T09:44:01.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 22,
      "pandit_activity_id": 14,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-26 15:25:46",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T09:55:46.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T09:55:46.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "pandit_activity_id": 7,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-26 16:04:40",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T10:34:40.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T10:34:40.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 24,
      "pandit_activity_id": 7,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-26 16:04:58",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T10:34:58.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T10:34:58.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "pandit_activity_id": 14,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-26 16:06:17",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T10:36:17.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T10:36:17.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 26,
      "pandit_activity_id": 14,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-26 16:06:31",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T10:36:31.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T10:36:31.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 27,
      "pandit_activity_id": 4,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-26 16:07:04",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T10:37:04.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T10:37:04.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 28,
      "pandit_activity_id": 4,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-26 16:07:14",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T10:37:14.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T10:37:14.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 29,
      "pandit_activity_id": 14,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-26 16:08:29",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T10:38:29.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T10:38:29.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 30,
      "pandit_activity_id": 14,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-26 16:08:37",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T10:38:37.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T10:38:37.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 31,
      "pandit_activity_id": 3,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-26 16:53:51",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T11:23:51.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T11:23:51.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 32,
      "pandit_activity_id": 3,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-26 16:54:22",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T11:24:22.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T11:24:22.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 33,
      "pandit_activity_id": 15,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-26 20:54:17",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T15:24:17.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T15:24:17.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 34,
      "pandit_activity_id": 15,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-26 20:54:31",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T15:24:31.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T15:24:31.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 35,
      "pandit_activity_id": 15,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-26 20:54:53",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T15:24:53.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T15:24:53.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 36,
      "pandit_activity_id": 15,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-26 20:55:03",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T15:25:03.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T15:25:03.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 37,
      "pandit_activity_id": 2,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-26 21:41:51",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T16:11:51.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T16:11:51.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 38,
      "pandit_activity_id": 2,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-26 21:44:37",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T16:14:37.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T16:14:37.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 39,
      "pandit_activity_id": 16,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-26 21:44:59",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T16:14:59.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T16:14:59.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 40,
      "pandit_activity_id": 16,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-26 21:45:03",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T16:15:03.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T16:15:03.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 41,
      "pandit_activity_id": 3,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-27 01:12:45",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T19:42:45.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T19:42:45.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 42,
      "pandit_activity_id": 3,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-27 01:12:48",
      "created_at": "2020-08-26T19:42:48.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-26T19:42:48.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 45,
      "pandit_activity_id": 16,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-31 14:48:36",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-31T09:18:36.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-31T09:18:36.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 46,
      "pandit_activity_id": 16,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": null,
      "checkOut": "2020-08-31 14:51:22",
      "created_at": "2020-08-31T09:21:22.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-31T09:21:22.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 47,
      "pandit_activity_id": 16,
      "pandit_id": 1,
      "checkIn": "2020-08-31 14:51:39",
      "checkOut": null,
      "created_at": "2020-08-31T09:21:39.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-08-31T09:21:39.000000Z"
    }
  ],
  "payments": [
    
  ]
}
```

User.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:PandeetApp/services/activity.dart';

class User {
  int id;
  String name;
  String mobile;
  String smsToken;
  String mobileVerifiedAt;
  String email;
  String emailToken;
  Null emailVerifiedAt;
  String password;
  String rememberToken;
  String avatar;
  String address;
  String city;
  String state;
  String country;
  int pincode;
  int locationId;
  String travelled;
  String adharcard;
  String pancard;
  String specialisation;
  List services;
  String minCharge;
  String maxCharge;
  String onlineCharge;
  String qualification;
  String experience;
  String language;
  String active;
  String varify;
  PaymentMode paymentMode;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;
  String rating;
  List<Clients> clients;
  List<Visits> visits;
  List<Payments> payments;

  User({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.mobile,
    this.smsToken,
    this.mobileVerifiedAt,
    this.email,
    this.emailToken,
    this.emailVerifiedAt,
    this.password,
    this.rememberToken,
    this.avatar,
    this.address,
    this.city,
    this.state,
    this.country,
    this.pincode,
    this.locationId,
    this.travelled,
    this.adharcard,
    this.pancard,
    this.specialisation,
    this.services,
    this.minCharge,
    this.maxCharge,
    this.onlineCharge,
    this.qualification,
    this.experience,
    this.language,
    this.active,
    this.varify,
    this.paymentMode,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.rating,
    this.clients,
    this.visits,
    this.payments,
  });

  Future<User> fetchData() async {
    var data = await PanditActivity().profile();
    // print(data);
    return new User.fromJson(data);
  }

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    mobile = json['mobile'];
    smsToken = json['sms_token'];
    mobileVerifiedAt = json['mobile_verified_at'];
    email = json['email'];
    emailToken = json['email_token'];
    emailVerifiedAt = json['email_verified_at'];
    password = json['password'];
    rememberToken = json['remember_token'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
    address = json['address'];
    city = json['city'];
    state = json['state'];
    country = json['country'];
    pincode = json['pincode'];
    locationId = json['location_id'];
    travelled = json['travelled'];
    adharcard = json['adharcard'];
    pancard = json['pancard'];
    specialisation = json['specialisation'];
    services = jsonDecode(json['services']) ?? [];
    minCharge = json['min_charge'];
    maxCharge = json['max_charge'];
    onlineCharge = json['online_charge'];
    qualification = json['qualification'];
    experience = json['experience'];
    language = json['language'];
    active = json['active'];
    varify = json['varify'];
    paymentMode = json['payment_mode'] != null
        ? new PaymentMode.fromJson(jsonDecode(json['payment_mode']))
        : PaymentMode();
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    rating = json['rating'];
    if (json['clients'] != null) {
      clients = new List<Clients>();
      json['clients'].forEach((v) {
        clients.add(new Clients.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['visits'] != null) {
      visits = new List<Visits>();
      json['visits'].forEach((v) {
        visits.add(new Visits.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['payments'] != null) {
      payments = new List<Payments>();
      json['payments'].forEach((v) {
        payments.add(new Payments.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, String> toJson() {
    final Map<String, String> data = new Map<String, String>();
    data['id'] = this.id.toString();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['mobile'] = this.mobile;
    data['sms_token'] = this.smsToken;
    data['mobile_verified_at'] = this.mobileVerifiedAt;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['email_token'] = this.emailToken;
    data['email_verified_at'] = this.emailVerifiedAt;
    data['password'] = this.password;
    data['remember_token'] = this.rememberToken;
    data['avatar'] = this.avatar;
    data['address'] = this.address;
    data['city'] = this.city;
    data['state'] = this.state;
    data['country'] = this.country;
    data['pincode'] = this.pincode.toString();
    data['location_id'] = this.locationId.toString();
    data['travelled'] = this.travelled;
    data['adharcard'] = this.adharcard;
    data['pancard'] = this.pancard;
    data['specialisation'] = this.specialisation;
    data['services'] = jsonEncode(this.services);
    data['min_charge'] = this.minCharge;
    data['max_charge'] = this.maxCharge;
    data['online_charge'] = this.onlineCharge;
    data['qualification'] = this.qualification;
    data['experience'] = this.experience;
    data['language'] = this.language;
    data['active'] = this.active;
    data['varify'] = this.varify;
    if (this.paymentMode != null) {
      data['payment_mode'] = jsonEncode(this.paymentMode.toJson());
    }
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    data['rating'] = this.rating;
    if (this.clients != null) {
      data['clients'] = this.clients.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList().toString();
    }
    if (this.visits != null) {
      data['visits'] = this.visits.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList().toString();
    }
    if (this.payments != null) {
      data['payments'] =
          this.payments.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList().toString();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class PaymentMode {
  String bankName;
  String bankAddress;
  String ifscCode;
  String accountNo;
  String accountHolder;

  PaymentMode(
      {this.bankName, this.ifscCode, this.accountNo, this.accountHolder});

  PaymentMode.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    bankName = json['bank_name'];
    bankAddress = json['bank_address'];
    ifscCode = json['ifsc_code'];
    accountNo = json['account_no'];
    accountHolder = json['account_holder'];
  }

  Map<String, String> toJson() {
    final Map<String, String> data = new Map<String, String>();
    data['bank_name'] = this.bankName;
    data['bank_address'] = this.bankAddress;
    data['ifsc_code'] = this.ifscCode;
    data['account_no'] = this.accountNo;
    data['account_holder'] = this.accountHolder;
    return data;
  }
}

class Clients {
  int id;
  int clientId;
  String perpose;
  String details;
  String when;
  int acceptedBy;
  String name;
  String mobile;
  String email;
  String orgName;
  String address;
  String city;
  String state;
  String pincode;
  String country;
  String latitude;
  String longitude;
  String clientIp;
  String device;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  Clients(
      {this.id,
      this.clientId,
      this.perpose,
      this.details,
      this.when,
      this.acceptedBy,
      this.name,
      this.mobile,
      this.email,
      this.orgName,
      this.address,
      this.city,
      this.state,
      this.pincode,
      this.country,
      this.latitude,
      this.longitude,
      this.clientIp,
      this.device,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  Clients.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    clientId = json['client_id'];
    perpose = json['perpose'];
    details = json['details'];
    when = json['when'];
    acceptedBy = json['accepted_by'];
    name = json['name'];
    mobile = json['mobile'];
    email = json['email'];
    orgName = json['org_name'];
    address = json['address'];
    city = json['city'];
    state = json['state'];
    pincode = json['pincode'];
    country = json['country'];
    latitude = json['latitude'];
    longitude = json['longitude'];
    clientIp = json['client_ip'];
    device = json['device'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, String> toJson() {
    final Map<String, String> data = new Map<String, String>();
    data['id'] = this.id.toString();
    data['client_id'] = this.clientId.toString();
    data['perpose'] = this.perpose;
    data['details'] = this.details;
    data['when'] = this.when;
    data['accepted_by'] = this.acceptedBy.toString();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['mobile'] = this.mobile;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['org_name'] = this.orgName;
    data['address'] = this.address;
    data['city'] = this.city;
    data['state'] = this.state;
    data['pincode'] = this.pincode;
    data['country'] = this.country;
    data['latitude'] = this.latitude;
    data['longitude'] = this.longitude;
    data['client_ip'] = this.clientIp;
    data['device'] = this.device;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}

class Visits {
  int id;
  int panditActivityId;
  int panditId;
  String checkIn;
  String checkOut;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  Visits(
      {this.id,
      this.panditActivityId,
      this.panditId,
      this.checkIn,
      this.checkOut,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  Visits.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    panditActivityId = json['pandit_activity_id'];
    panditId = json['pandit_id'];
    checkIn = json['checkIn'];
    checkOut = json['checkOut'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, String> toJson() {
    final Map<String, String> data = new Map<String, String>();
    data['id'] = this.id.toString();
    data['pandit_activity_id'] = this.panditActivityId.toString();
    data['pandit_id'] = this.panditId.toString();
    data['checkIn'] = this.checkIn;
    data['checkOut'] = this.checkOut;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}

class Payments {
  int id;
  int panditId;
  String details;
  String mode;
  String creditAmt;
  String debitAmt;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  Payments(
      {this.id,
      this.panditId,
      this.details,
      this.mode,
      this.creditAmt,
      this.debitAmt,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  Payments.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    panditId = json['pandit_id'];
    details = json['details'];
    mode = json['mode'];
    creditAmt = json['credit_amt'].toString();
    debitAmt = json['debit_amt'].toString();
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, String> toJson() {
    final Map<String, String> data = new Map<String, String>();
    data['id'] = this.id.toString();
    data['pandit_id'] = this.panditId.toString();
    data['details'] = this.details;
    data['mode'] = this.mode;
    data['credit_amt'] = this.creditAmt;
    data['debit_amt'] = this.debitAmt;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I think may be problems comes from this user.dart. But i am not understand, where is the problem. Thank you to all.

Comment: Post your `quickInfo` method.

Comment: I am added the code.

Comment: Use this instead: `user.clients != null ? user.clients.length.toString() : '0'` in your `quickInfo` method for the `Total Clients`.

Comment: I used it. But problem is same.

Comment: You are still getting `The getter 'length' was called on null` or some `Users` Total Clients aren't displaying ?

Comment: I am already post Rest API Data Sample. in the above. Some User details works fine. But on this data sample not Working.